# How do i achieve a border like this?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to achieve a border like the way http://urustar.net/ do on their boxes.

The boxes are the things if you scroll down a bit on the page. It says "Hi we are a tiny company..."

Cheers everyone!

Comment: That's not a border, it uses an [image](http://urustar.net/css/about-title.jpg) for background

Comment: Did you check their page source?

Comment: -1 why to bother to look up the source of the page itself? It is so much easier to post a question here and wait if you find an idiot that does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually called a ribbon. You can google for "CSS ribbon" and you'll even find things like this:

http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the actual banner that contains "Hi we are a tiny company...", it is an image overlaying...

But if you want to border like the rounded corner with white strobe. It is the css similar to this:

```
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px white solid;
```

Let me know if this helps. Thank you